# ggplotly removes legend from ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

ggplotly removes the legend of a geom_line plot using ggplot.

See e.g. below:

```
library(plotly)    
g <- ggplot(iris)
g = g + geom_line(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, color = Species), size = 0.05)
g # Here is a legend
(gg <- ggplotly(g)) # Legend has now been removed.
```

Any ideas how to get back the legend?

I am using plotly_2.0.19 and ggplot2_2.0.0.9000.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For some reason `ggplotly` never adds a legend for `geom_line`. The documentation only has legends when points are also added. I suggest using transparent points as a work around.

```
{ ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, color = Species)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(alpha = 0) } %>%
  ggplotly()
```

[image]